# How to clone and modify rows in SQL table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I use MSSQL 2012.

I have this table called SensorMeasure:

```
| Id | SensorUnitId| MeasureDate            | AlertType | MeasureValue|   
| 1  |   3379      | 2016-06-05 00:01:34.000|         1 |     4       | 
| 3  |   3381      | 2016-09-18 11:26:33.000|         6 |     5       |
| 4  |   3381      | 2017-03-03 21:46:18.000|         3 |     3       |
| 5  |   3382      | 2016-09-18 11:26:33.000|         5 |     8       |
| 6  |   3381      | 2017-05-03 21:46:18.000|         3 |     0       |
```

I need to gruop the rows by SensorUnitId column then after groupping by SensorUnitId I need to clone rows which has latest date, set `AlertType` cell to 6 and set current date and time to `MeasureDate` cell and insert them into the table.

Here the result I expect:

```
| Id | SensorUnitId| MeasureDate            | AlertType | MeasureValue|   
| 1  |   3379      | 2016-06-05 00:01:34.000|         1 |     4       | 
| 3  |   3381      | 2016-09-18 11:26:33.000|         6 |     5       |
| 4  |   3381      | 2017-03-03 21:46:18.000|         4 |     3       |
| 5  |   3382      | 2016-09-18 11:26:33.000|         5 |     8       |
| 6  |   3381      | 2016-11-03 21:46:18.000|         3 |     0       |
| 7  |   3379      | 2016-12-12 15:30:34.000|         6 |     4       | 
| 8  |   3381      | 2016-12-12 15:30:34.000|         6 |     0       |
| 9  |   3382      | 2016-12-12 15:30:34.000|         6 |     8       |
```

Here how I group the rows:

```
SELECT  Max(MeasureDate) as Date, MAX(AlertType) as AlertType,SensorUnitId
FROM SensorsMeasure
GROUP BY SensorUnitId
```

But I don't know how after grouping I modify MeasureDate to current date and time and how to set AlertType to 6 and insert those rows to the table.

**UPDATE**

As I already wrote I have table named SensorMeasure.I need to group all records in the table by column `SensorUnitId`.

After records were grouped I need to fetch from each gruop record with the latest date.If the fetched record has `AlertType` value 6 I need to filter it(ignore it) if record has `AlertType` value not 6 I need to clone this row 
set `AlertType` cell to 6 and set current date and time to `MeasureDate` cell and insert them into the table `SensorMeasure`.

For example I have this table:

```
| Id | SensorUnitId|      MeasureDate       | AlertType | MeasureValue|   
| 1  |   3379      | 2016-06-05 00:01:34.000|         1 |     4       | 
| 3  |   3381      | 2016-09-18 11:26:33.000|         6 |     5       |
| 4  |   3381      | 2016-12-03 21:46:18.000|         3 |     3       |
| 5  |   3382      | 2016-09-18 11:26:33.000|         6 |     8       |
```

The desired table is:

```
| Id | SensorUnitId|      MeasureDate       | AlertType | MeasureValue|   
| 1  |   3379      | 2016-06-05 00:01:34.000|         1 |     4       | 
| 3  |   3381      | 2016-09-01 11:26:33.000|         6 |     5       |
| 4  |   3381      | 2016-12-03 21:46:18.000|         3 |     3       |
| 5  |   3382      | 2016-09-18 11:26:33.000|         6 |     8       |
| 6  |   3379      | 2016-12-12 21:20:34.000|         6 |     4       | 
| 7  |   3381      | 2016-12-12 21:20:34.000|         6 |     3       |
```

Comment: I removed my answer @sqlzim has more comprehensive one.

Comment: There are two (substantial) answers below Michael, are you able to accept one?

Answer (score 2):

**Latest update**

This is my rephrasing of the question as I understand it:

> If the most recent entry (by `MeasureDate`) for each `SensorUnitId` does not have `AlertType = 6`, I need to insert a new row into that table for that `SensorUnitId` with the current date, a new `AlertType`, and the most recent `MeasurementValue`.

I believe the easiest way to do this is with **cross [apply](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)**.

rextester: **http://rextester.com/VBP95454**

```
/* testing setup */
create table SensorsMeasure (Id int,SensorUnitId int,MeasureDate datetime,AlertType int,MeasureValue int)
insert into  SensorsMeasure (Id,SensorUnitId,MeasureDate,AlertType,MeasureValue) values (1,3379,'2016-06-05 00:01:34.000',1,4),(3,3381,'2016-09-18 11:26:33.000',6,5),(4,3381,'2016-12-03 21:46:18.000',3,3),(5,3382,'2016-09-18 11:26:33.000',6,8)
declare @NewAlertType int   ; set @NewAlertType    = 6;
declare @ExceptAlertType int; set @ExceptAlertType = 6;

select * from SensorsMeasure;

--**`cross [apply][4]`** version:

--insert into SensorsMeasure (SensorUnitId, MeasureDate, AlertType, MeasureValue)
select distinct
    SensorUnitId
  , MeasureDate  =   getdate()
  , AlertType    =  @NewAlertType
  , MeasureValue = x.MeasureValue
from SensorsMeasure sm
  cross apply (select top 1 MeasureValue, AlertType
                      from SensorsMeasure i
                      where i.SensorUnitId = sm.SensorUnitId
                      order by MeasureDate desc) as x
where x.AlertType != @ExceptAlertType;
```

You can also do this with **[top with ties](http://sqlmag.com/t-sql/use-top-filter-with-ties-option)** (without needing to use cross or outer apply in this instance).

rextester: **http://rextester.com/JWT74538**

```
--insert into SensorsMeasure (SensorUnitId, MeasureDate, AlertType, MeasureValue)
select top 1 with ties
      sm.SensorUnitId
    , MeasureDate = getdate() 
    , AlertType   = @NewAlertType
    , sm.MeasureValue
  from  SensorsMeasure sm
  where sm.AlertType != @ExceptAlertType
  order by row_number() over (partition by sm.SensorUnitId order by sm.MeasureDate desc);
```

---

Previous Update:

It looks like I made an assumption that it was the max alert type based on the example data. Instead you could just use `AlertType = 6`.

Updated to the reflect updated question :

> I need to ignore recordes after group by that has `AlertType = 6`.

Which I interpret to mean ignore `SensorUnitIds` that have had an `AlertType` of `6`

rextester link for test code: **http://rextester.com/CLA47054**

```
/* testing setup */
create table SensorsMeasure (Id int,SensorUnitId int,MeasureDate datetime,AlertType int,MeasureValue int)
insert into  SensorsMeasure (Id,SensorUnitId,MeasureDate,AlertType,MeasureValue) values (1,3379,'2016-06-05 00:01:34.000',1,4),(3,3381,'2016-09-18 11:26:33.000',6,5),(4,3381,'2017-03-03 21:46:18.000',3,3),(5,3382,'2016-09-18 11:26:33.000',5,8),(6,3381,'2017-05-03 21:46:18.000',3,0);
declare @NewAlertType    int; set @NewAlertType    = 7;
declare @ExceptAlertType int; set @ExceptAlertType = 6;
```

**[correlated supquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery)** version:

```
--insert into SensorsMeasure (SensorUnitId, MeasureDate, AlertType, MeasureValue)
  select
      SensorUnitId
    , MeasureDate  = getdate()
    , AlertType    = @NewAlertType
    , MeasureValue = (select top 1 MeasureValue
                        from SensorsMeasure i
                        where i.SensorUnitId = sm.SensorUnitId
                        order by MeasureDate desc)
  from SensorsMeasure sm
  where not exists (
    select 1
      from SensorsMeasure e
      where e.SensorUnitId = sm.SensorUnitId
        and e.AlertType    = @ExceptAlertType
        )
  group by SensorUnitId;
```

**[common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx)** with **[row_number()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx)** version:

```
;with LatestMeasureValue as (
  select
      SensorUnitId
    , MeasureValue
    , rn=row_number() over (partition by SensorUnitId order by MeasureDate desc)
    from SensorsMeasure sm
    where not exists (
    select 1
      from SensorsMeasure e
      where e.SensorUnitId = sm.SensorUnitId
        and e.AlertType    = @ExceptAlertType
        )
)
--insert into SensorsMeasure (SensorUnitId, MeasureDate, AlertType, MeasureValue)
  select
      lmv.SensorUnitId
    , MeasureDate  = getdate()
    , AlertType    = @NewAlertType
    , MeasureValue = lmv.MeasureValue
  from LatestMeasureValue lmv
  where lmv.rn=1
```

**cross [apply](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)** version:

```
--insert into SensorsMeasure (SensorUnitId, MeasureDate, AlertType, MeasureValue)
select distinct
    SensorUnitId
  , MeasureDate  =   getdate()
  , AlertType    =  @NewAlertType
  , MeasureValue = x.MeasureValue
from SensorsMeasure sm
  cross apply (select top 1 MeasureValue
                      from SensorsMeasure i
                      where i.SensorUnitId = sm.SensorUnitId
                      order by MeasureDate desc) as x
  where not exists (
    select 1
      from SensorsMeasure e
      where e.SensorUnitId = sm.SensorUnitId
        and e.AlertType    = @ExceptAlertType
        )
```

---

old answer:

```
;with LatestMeasureValue as (
  select
      SensorUnitId
    , MeasureValue
    , rn=row_number() over (partition by SensorUnitId order by MeasureDate desc)
    from SensorsMeasure
)
insert into SensorsMeasure (SensorUnitId, MeasureDate, AlertType, MeasureValue)
  select
      lmv.SensorUnitId
    , MeasureDate = getdate()
    , mat.MaxAlertType
    , lmv.MeasureValue
  from LatestMeasureValue lmv
    cross join (
      select
        MaxAlertType=max(AlertType)
      from SensorsMeasure
      ) as mat
  where lmv.rn=1
```

This uses a [common table expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) to get the latest `MeasureValue` for each `SensorUnitId`, and cross joins a query to get the `max(AlertType)` to add the greatest `AlertType` to each of the latest values, and finally uses `getdate()` to serve as the new `MeasureDate`

You can also do this some other ways.

This method just uses a subquery and a [correlated subquery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlated_subquery):

```
insert into SensorsMeasure (SensorUnitId, MeasureDate, AlertType, MeasureValue)
  select
      SensorUnitId
    , MeasureDate  = getdate()
    , AlertType    = (select max(AlertType) from SensorsMeasure)
    , MeasureValue = (select top 1 MeasureValue
                        from SensorsMeasure i
                        where i.SensorUnitId = sm.SensorUnitId
                        order by MeasureDate desc)
  from SensorsMeasure sm
  group by SensorUnitId;
```

Comment: `AlertType` I suppose is constantly 6.

Comment: @SqlZim thank you. Where do I change AlertType currently it 6 bu it might be change?

Comment: It looks like I made an assumption that it was the max alert type based on the example data. Instead you can just write `AlertType = 6`

Comment: @SqlZim, Is there any way to change you code that way that after groupping the rows that selected with AlertType not equal to 6?

Comment: I have updated my answer. Can you try clarify exactly what you mean with the updated question with more example data and example results? I'm not sure my interpretation of your request is correct.

Comment: @SqlZim I am very sorry for confusion.I updated the question and  I  wrote additional example.Please see it.

Comment: No worries. I updated my answer, let me know if that isn't what you wanted.

Comment: Thanks for feedback.I tryed your update it's works fine except one row which every time is inserted when I fire   the function.

`548071984 2016-12-13 09:30:54.130 -1 6 57943`

Any idea what may  cause to this behavior?

Comment: That has more values than I would expect. Can you post the whole target table schema (right click - script as create)? I'm assuming  (SensorUnitId = 548071984, MeasureDate = '2016-12-13 09:30:54.130', AlertType = -1, MeasureValue = 6, Unknown = 57943).

Answer (score 1):

One more way using [TOP WITH TIES](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) + [ROW_NUMBER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx):

```
DECLARE  @alerttype int = 6

--INSERT INTO SensorMeasure
SELECT top 1 with ties
        s.SensorUnitId,
        GETDATE() as MeasureDate,
        @alerttype as AlertType,
        s.MeasureValue
FROM SensorMeasure S
left join (select distinct SensorUnitId from SensorMeasure where AlertType =6) s1 
on s1.SensorUnitId = s.SensorUnitId 
WHERE s1.SensorUnitId is null
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.SensorUnitId ORDER BY s.MeasureDate DESC)
```

Output:

```
SensorUnitId MeasureDate             AlertType   MeasureValue
------------ ----------------------- ----------- ------------
3379         2016-12-12 17:06:35.953 6           4
3382         2016-12-12 17:06:35.953 6           8

(2 row(s) affected)
```

**EDIT**

If you need only latest and not with `AlertType = 6` you can add some [OUTER APPLY](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156(v=sql.105).aspx)

```
DECLARE  @alerttype int = 6

--INSERT INTO SensorMeasure
SELECT top 1 with ties
        s.SensorUnitId,
        GETDATE() as MeasureDate,
        @alerttype as AlertType,
        s.MeasureValue
FROM SensorMeasure S
OUTER APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 * 
    FROM SensorMeasure 
    WHERE SensorUnitId = s.SensorUnitId 
    ORDER BY MeasureDate DESC
        ) s1 
WHERE s1.AlertType != @alerttype
ORDER BY ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY s.SensorUnitId ORDER BY s.MeasureDate DESC)
```

Output:

```
SensorUnitId MeasureDate             AlertType   MeasureValue
------------ ----------------------- ----------- ------------
3379         2016-12-13 10:05:39.377 6           4
3381         2016-12-13 10:05:39.377 6           3

(2 row(s) affected)
```

Comment: Update my answer! Check it out!

Comment: Nothing. At first I start writing what to add, then realize that I can just add this directly to query.

Comment: yeas sorry.I have strange behavor It's works fine for all rows except one,  this  row: `548071984 2016-12-13 09:30:54.130 -1 6`

each time it inrseted into the table when function is fired even if it already create with value 6 in AlertType cell.

Comment: Do you have triggers on this table?

Comment: No I don't have triggers

Comment: If there is no triggers you can check `SensorMeasure` table creation script. Maybe there are some calculated fields.